# Xbian does not allow harddisk to stand-by for long

Tags: hard-drive, xbian

I have an external 2TB WD Elemens harddisk recently purchased plugged into the USB of my Raspberry Pi with Xbian 1.0 beta 2 installed. This disk has internal power management so it enters stand-by mode after approx 30 minutes of not being read or written. So, although the disk does stop (spin down) after a while when no one uses the Pi, it spins up again after 10-15 minutes without any external intervention.

Why could this happen, what could be accessing it? I did the following things trying to prevent daemons from read/writing it and figure out what's causing it:

1. Added `exit 0` before any command in `/etc/init.d/hdparm`, `ntp`, `rsync`, `anacron`, `smartmontools`, `smartd`
2. Commented everything out in `/etc/init/anacron.conf`, `cron.conf`
3. Commented all out in `/etc/cron.*/0anacron` files
4. Commented all out in `/etc/crontab`
5. Added `exit 0` before all commands in `/etc/apm/event.d/*` and   `/etc/apm/other.d/ifplugd`
6. Tested on Openelec - here the non-needed spin-up down does not occur, the disk stays on stand-by undefinetely if the Pi is not used
7. I unmounted the disk and this still happens, so perhaps some kind of diagnostic request is sent to it through USB, but by which program?
8. Mounted the disk with `noatime`, no success.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: I have a B+ with XBian beta3, I don't have this issue, have you considered to run an update to the latest version?

Comment: My first thought was that it might be the updatedb cron, but since you've gotten that taken care of I looked a bit more. There is a handy trick to cause the kernel to dump everytime something access the disk: http://serverfault.com/questions/44294/how-can-i-tell-whats-spinning-up-my-drive

Comment: Is the system log written to the disk in question?

Comment: You can use audit to log all the disk activities. Just keep in mind not to make audit write to that disk.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the WD power management and Xbian drive management don't work together, at least on beta2. Look at [this post](http://forum.xbian.org/thread-1974-post-19459.html#pid19459). Disable the disk's internal power management and let Xbian run the show.